# looping through a imacro macro and wait for fileupload to finish

Tags: vbscript, imacros

Hi i want to upload multiple videos to a video site and i want to use imacros for that. (i use a csv for file names tags etc)

ATM i set a high wait time after i "press upload" and then start to upload the next video.
(sometimes it starts a new uplaod to early or wait way to long >_>) I want to optimize this by checking if the upload is finished and then starting the next upload.

i looked up how to use vbs script with imacro but the only sample i found was in javascript and i dont understand what it does :o

can someone pls explain the program logic i should use?

from this javascript sample i understand that i need 3 macros: 1. for website login, 2. for fileupload and 3. for checking if the upload is done.
And use some loop in the vbs to control the stuff

I hope someone can help me:)

So far i think i found all i need but i cant put it together :(

javascript sample (3rd post explains how to use the wait[i guess]);
http://forum.iopus.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12622

and i need to pass a variable from vbs to imacros (so that the jumps to next row in the csv)sample:
http://forum.iopus.com/viewtopic.php?t=8189

My macro atm:

```
VERSION BUILD=8021970
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=websitelink

SET !DATASOURCE videodaa.csv

SET !LOOP 2

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

WAIT SECONDS=1

'upload file selection'
SIZE X=1067 Y=845
WAIT SECONDS=0.594
DS CMD=MOVETO X=28 Y=417 CONTENT=
WAIT SECONDS=0.587

DS CMD=MOVETO X=105 Y=152 CONTENT=
WAIT SECONDS=0.000
DS CMD=LDOWN X=105 Y=152 CONTENT=
WAIT SECONDS=0.509
DS CMD=LUP X=105 Y=152 CONTENT=
WAIT SECONDS=0.435

DS CMD=KEY CONTENT={{!COL1}}{ENTER}
WAIT SECONDS=0.5
'restof the script'

'terms checkbox'
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:at&&VALUE:on CONTENT=YES
WAIT SECONDS=1.035

'titel'
DS CMD=CLICK X=100 Y=406 CONTENT=
WAIT SECONDS=1.0
DS CMD=KEY CONTENT={{!COL2}}
WAIT SECONDS=1
'category'

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:category CONTENT=%1
WAIT SECONDS=1.235
'description'
DS CMD=CLICK X=206 Y=560 CONTENT=
DS CMD=KEY CONTENT={{!COL2}}
wait SECONDS=1
'press upload button '
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON:SUBMIT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:sbc&&VALUE:start<SP>my<SP>upload

'wait 2 min for upload to finish and start over"
wait SECONDS=120
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

The example you showed is Java and not JavaScript. After FireFox 16, Java is no longer supported in FireFox.

In this example you can see how to write JavaScript macro.
[Check if html element exists with iMacros and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174655/check-if-html-element-exists-with-imacros-and-javascript/16199825?noredirect=1#comment23191008_16199825)

Do not use X Y positioning use Conventional when recording a macro. Also DS command is no longer supported in newer versions of iMacros.

Hope it helps.