# Imacros Javascript: Check If Element Exist UNDER Multiple Lines Condition

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am trying to check if the element *does* exist in webpage.

I saw how it's done in this simple stuff previously,
[Check if html element exists with iMacros and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174655/check-if-html-element-exists-with-imacros-and-javascript)

(I want to comment there, but it said need 50 rep minimum)

The simple stuff I meant was like this.

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:some_class CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER ";

var ret=null;

ret=iimPlay(macro);

if(ret>0)
{
//do something
}
else
{
//do something else
}
```

But unfortunately, when it comes to several line check..
As I needed to add , to make the whole proccess running more efficiently..

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 2
```

The return of this *ret* variable will always 1 (I prompted it's value with different cases).
So the else condition will never met.

### What should I do?

UPDATE: (actual case)
The case here, element of webpage is not visible until you scrolled to it. Say you are on Facebook. The button "Add Comment" is **not visible** until you're scrolled to the article element. It would work with this algorithm.

```
// loop start
for(;;){
  iimplaycode(*hover tag:nth-of-type(i)*);

  x=iimplaycode(*check if add comment is there*);

  if(x>0){
    //if it's there, do comment
     iimplaycode();
  }
  //loop to 2nd element
}
```

See the problem now? If I am not using the `!TIMEOUT_STEP`, the checking of "add comment" would be take long (6 second).. Just want to maximize performance by lowering it's value to 1,2 seconds or so.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? do you want to know to create a loop using javascript and IMacros? give the GIST of what the problem is!

Comment: @NarenMurali updated thread of exact problem I am facing